# How to change Color Scheme for vue template in WebStorm?

Tags: webstorm

### The question is that I want the color scheme inside the vue files to be like this

[image]

That's what I have now

[image]

Color Scheme setup - One Dark

Have no Vue directory in color Schemes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved - rainbow bracket (plugin) blocks this feature.